# Jinja2 looping through a python list to return each item in xml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, jinja2

I have a python list returning ['a','b','c'] I want to use this list to display each item individually using Jinja2 templating.

I have tried using batch(1):

```
{% for resource in resourcelist|batch(1) %}
            <file {{ resource }} >
{% endfor %}
```

However this is still returning the answer as a list:

file ['a', 'b', 
    'c']>

And I have used endif but was unable to get the code to run.

The xml file with Jinja2 templating is:

```
<resources>
<resource identifier="resource" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" 
href="{{starting_resource}}">
{% for resource in resourcelist %}
            <file {{ resource }} >
{% endfor %}
</resource>
```

The output I am currently getting is:

```
<resource identifier="resource" type="webcontent" 
adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="df/res/test.hml">

        <file df/res/test.hml >

        <file ['a', 'b', 'c'] >

</resource>
```

The python code:

```
mylist = [index, all_resources]

output = template.render(starting_resource = index, resourcelist = 
mylist)
```

The output I would like is:

```
<resource identifier="resource" type="webcontent" 
adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="df/res/test.hml">

        <file df/res/test.hml >

        <file ['a'] >

        <file ['b'] >

        <file ['c'] >

</resource>
```

Suggested appreciated I am brand new to Jinja templating.

**My goal is to be able to extract all files from a directory and list them using Jinja2 templating in an XML page.**

Comment: Show us how `resourcelist` is populated.  It sounds like it's a list-of-lists.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have added the template.render section from my python code which highlights the resourcelist creation, it is a list-of-lists.

Comment: Okay, so `resourcelist` is indeed a list of lists.  So when you iterate over it in the template, each value you get is itself also a list.  Perhaps you need another loop `{% for file in resource %}` inside the main loop?

Comment: If you are attempting an XML file, that is not a well-formed output as `<file>` tags do not close and square brackets, `[` and `]`, are strangely used reflecting neither an attribute or element value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider avoiding the repeat assignment of *index* in Python and simply reference *starting_resource* twice in Jinja. Below also properly uses attributes and closing tags for a well-formed XML output.

**Python** script *(no need for mylist variable)*

```py
output = template.render(starting_resource = index, resourcelist = all_resources)
```

**Jinja** template

```
<resources>
    <resource identifier="resource" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" 
              href="{{starting_resource}}">
            <file href="{{starting_resource}}" /> 
      {% for resource in resourcelist %}
            <file href="{{resource}}" />
      {% endfor %}
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Amazing thats working for me, so I see the issue I was having as my for loop was running through two lists and separating them allowed the loop to loop through just the list itself. Thank you